# BlackJack Java Code Testing

Tags: java, computer-science, blackjack

I am having a problem testing blackjack java code, this is the following code:

```
package view;

/*
////In this applet, the user plays a game of Blackjack.  The
////computer acts as the dealer.  The user plays by clicking
////"Hit!" and "Stand!" buttons.

////The programming of this applet assumes that the applet is
////set up to be about 466 pixels wide and about 346 pixels high.
////That width is just big enough to show 2 rows of 5 cards.
////The height is probably a little bigger than necessary,
////to allow for variations in the size of buttons from one platform
////to another.

*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import model.Card;
import model.Deck;
import model.Hand;

public class GUI21 extends JApplet {

public void init() {

  // The init() method creates components and lays out the applet.
  // A BlackjackCanvas occupies the CENTER position of the layout.
  // On the bottom is a panel that holds three buttons.  The
  // BlackjackCanvas object listens for events from the buttons
  // and does all the real work of the program.

setBackground( new Color(130,50,40) );

BlackjackCanvas board = new BlackjackCanvas();
getContentPane().add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setBackground( new Color(220,200,180) );
getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JButton hit = new JButton( "Hit!" );
hit.addActionListener(board);
buttonPanel.add(hit);

JButton stand = new JButton( "Stand!" );
stand.addActionListener(board);
buttonPanel.add(stand);

JButton newGame = new JButton( "New Game" );
newGame.addActionListener(board);
buttonPanel.add(newGame);

}  // end init()

public Insets getInsets() {
  // Specify how much space to leave between the edges of
  // the applet and the components it contains.  The background
  // color shows through in this border.
return new Insets(3,3,3,3);
}


// --- The remainder of this class consists of a nested class ---


class BlackjackCanvas extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

  // A nested class that displays the card game and does all the work
  // of keeping track of the state and responding to user events.

Deck deck;         // A deck of cards to be used in the game.

Hand dealerHand;   // Hand containing the dealer's cards.
Hand playerHand;   // Hand containing the user's cards.

String message;  // A message drawn on the canvas, which changes
                //    to reflect the state of the game.

boolean gameInProgress;  // Set to true when a game begins and to false
                        //   when the game ends.

Font bigFont;      // Font that will be used to display the message.
Font smallFont;    // Font that will be used to draw the cards.


BlackjackCanvas() {
     // Constructor.  Creates fonts and starts the first game.
  setBackground( new Color(0,120,0) );
  smallFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
  bigFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
  doNewGame();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      // Respond when the user clicks on a button by calling
      // the appropriate procedure.  Note that the canvas is
      // registered as a listener in the GUI21 class.
  String command = evt.getActionCommand();
  if (command.equals("Hit!"))
     doHit();
  else if (command.equals("Stand!"))
     doStand();
  else if (command.equals("New Game"))
     doNewGame();
}


void doHit() {
      // This method is called when the user clicks the "Hit!" button.
      // First check that a game is actually in progress.  If not, give
      // an error message and exit.  Otherwise, give the user a card.
      // The game can end at this point if the user goes over 21 or
      // if the user has taken 5 cards without going over 21.
  if (gameInProgress == false) {
     message = "Click \"New Game\" to start a new game.";
     repaint();
     return;
  }
  playerHand.addCard( deck.takeCardfromDeck() );
  if ( playerHand.getScore() > 21 ) {
     message = "You've busted!  Sorry, you lose.";
     gameInProgress = false;
  }
  else if (playerHand.getScore() == 5) {
     message = "You win by taking 5 cards without going over 21.";
     gameInProgress = false;
  }
  else {
     message = "You have " + playerHand.getScore() + ".  Hit or Stand?";
  }
  repaint();
}


void doStand() {
       // This method is called when the user clicks the "Stand!" button.
       // Check whether a game is actually in progress.  If it is,
       // the game ends.  The dealer takes cards until either the
       // dealer has 5 cards or more than 16 points.  Then the 
       // winner of the game is determined.
  if (gameInProgress == false) {
     message = "Click \"New Game\" to start a new game.";
     repaint();
     return;
  }
  gameInProgress = false;
  while (dealerHand.getScore() <= 16 && dealerHand.getCardsinHand() < 5)
     dealerHand.addCard( deck.takeCardfromDeck() );
  if (dealerHand.getScore() > 21)
      message = "You win!  Dealer has busted with " + dealerHand.getCardsinHand() +".";
  else if (dealerHand.getScore() == 5)
      message = "Sorry, you lose.  Dealer took 5 cards without going over 21.";
  else if (dealerHand.getScore() > playerHand.getScore())
      message = "Sorry, you lose, " + dealerHand.getScore()
                                        + " to " + playerHand.getScore() + ".";
  else if (dealerHand.getScore() == playerHand.getScore())
      message = "Sorry, you lose.  Dealer wins on a tie.";
  else
      message = "You win, " + playerHand.getScore()
                                        + " to " + dealerHand.getScore() + "!";
  repaint();
  }


  void doNewGame() {
      // Called by the constructor, and called by actionPerformed() if
      // the use clicks the "New Game" button.  Start a new game.
      // Deal two cards to each player.  The game might end right then
      // if one of the players had blackjack.  Otherwise, gameInProgress
      // is set to true and the game begins.
  if (gameInProgress) {
          // If the current game is not over, it is an error to try
          // to start a new game.
     message = "You still have to finish this game!";
     repaint();
     return;
  }
  deck = new Deck();   // Create the deck and hands to use for this game.
  dealerHand = new Hand();
  playerHand = new Hand();
  deck.shuffle();
  dealerHand.addCard( deck.takeCardfromDeck() );  // Deal two cards to each player.
  dealerHand.addCard( deck.takeCardfromDeck() );
  playerHand.addCard( deck.takeCardfromDeck() );
  playerHand.addCard( deck.takeCardfromDeck() );
  if (dealerHand.getScore() == 21) {
      message = "Sorry, you lose.  Dealer has Blackjack.";
      gameInProgress = false;
  }
  else if (playerHand.getScore() == 21) {
      message = "You win!  You have Blackjack.";
      gameInProgress = false;
  }
  else {
      message = "You have " + playerHand.getScore() + ".  Hit or stand?";
      gameInProgress = true;
  }
  repaint();
  }  // end newGame();


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     // The paint method shows the message at the bottom of the
     // canvas, and it draws all of the dealt cards spread out
     // across the canvas.

  super.paintComponent(g); // fill with background color.

  g.setFont(bigFont);
  g.setColor(Color.green);
  g.drawString(message, 10, getSize().height - 10);

  // Draw labels for the two sets of cards.

  g.drawString("Dealer's Cards:", 10, 23);
  g.drawString("Your Cards:", 10, 153);

  // Draw dealer's cards.  Draw first card face down if
  // the game is still in progress,  It will be revealed
  // when the game ends.

  g.setFont(smallFont);
  if (gameInProgress)
     drawCard(g, null, 10, 30);
  else
     drawCard(g, dealerHand.getCard(0), 10, 30);
  for (int i = 1; i < dealerHand.getCardsinHand(); i++)
     drawCard(g, dealerHand.getCard(i), 10 + i * 90, 30);

  // Draw the user's cards.

  for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.getCardsinHand(); i++)
     drawCard(g, playerHand.getCard(i), 10 + i * 90, 160);

  }  // end paint();


  void drawCard(Graphics g, Card card, int x, int y) {
       // Draws a card as a 80 by 100 rectangle with
       // upper left corner at (x,y).  The card is drawn
       // in the graphics context g.  If card is null, then
       // a face-down card is drawn.  (The cards are 
       // rather primitive.)
  if (card == null) {  
         // Draw a face-down card
     g.setColor(Color.blue);
     g.fillRect(x,y,80,100);
     g.setColor(Color.white);
     g.drawRect(x+3,y+3,73,93);
     g.drawRect(x+4,y+4,71,91);
  }
  else {
     g.setColor(Color.white);
     g.fillRect(x,y,80,100);
     g.setColor(Color.gray);
     g.drawRect(x,y,79,99);
     g.drawRect(x+1,y+1,77,97);
     if (card.getSuit() == card.getSuit() || card.getSuit() == card.getSuit())
        g.setColor(Color.red);
     else
        g.setColor(Color.black);
     g.drawString(card.toSymbol(), x + 10, y + 30);
     g.drawString("of", x+ 10, y + 50);
     g.drawString(card.toSymbol(), x + 10, y + 70);

  }  // end drawCard()


  } // end nested class BlackjackCanvas

  }
  } // end class HighLowGUI
```

However I receive this following error whenever I test it:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at model.Card.toSymbol(Card.java:38)
    at view.GUI21$BlackjackCanvas.drawCard(GUI21.java:266)
    at view.GUI21$BlackjackCanvas.paintComponent(GUI21.java:232)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions would be great, thank you.

Comment: Try cutting out a lot of the code. Give us just the part that is given you trouble and any other things necessary to understanding it. The wall of code approach is too hard to decifer.

Comment: What line do you get an error on?

Comment: It's not just a wall of code -- it's completely ***irrelevant*** code as you're not showing the right class. Where's the Card class, specifically line 38? You should read the error message before coming here as it tells you where the problem is: `at model.Card.toSymbol(Card.java:38)`

Comment: My apologies people for the inconvenience, I have solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the top of the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at model.Card.toSymbol(Card.java:38)
```

That's telling you there's something wrong happening in the `toSymbol()` method of your `Card` class (which you haven't posted, btw).  And what's wrong is that your `toSymbol()` method is apparently using a bad format string, or at least a format string that doesn't match the data that are to be formatted using it.  So look at the format string and read the Javadocs for format specifiers and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Thank you @QuantumMechanic, I was not paying attention to the above, I have solved the issue now, thanks again.